# Squeak Circle Section

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, morphic

I'm trying to draw  a quarter of a circle with Morphic in Squeak-Smalltalk.
How does it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best teacher is the the image itself. If you open a browser on CircleMorph, you'll see that its superclass, EllipseMorph, defines #drawOn:, which is how morphs draw themselves. From there, you can get all the information and inspiration to make your custom morph.

**Update:** My first thought was to draw it by hand (totally override #drawOn:), but there weren't any obvious candidates in Canvas. By letting the circle draw itself while setting the clipping rectangle to a quarter of it, it became almost a one-liner.

**Update 2:** The trick with a quarter-circle is getting CircleMorph to do most of the work for you! The best I came up with is:

```
QuarterCircleMorph>>drawOn: aCanvas

    | realBounds |
    "Save the actual bounds of the morph"
    realBounds := bounds.

    "Pretend the bounds are 4x as big"
    bounds := bounds bottom: bounds bottom + bounds height.
    bounds := bounds right: bounds right + bounds width.

    "Let CircleMorph handle the drawing"
    super drawOn: aCanvas.

    "Restore the actual bounds"
    bounds := realBounds.
```

Where QuarterCircleMorph is a subclass of CircleMorph. Because you can't draw past it's real bounds, everything works out. n.b. in actual code, the comments would be overkill (except maybe the 4x one, but then, that's a sign to maybe refactor :))

Comment: Thank you, but it wasn't so helpful. I don't get the point. The EllipseMorphs draw method: `code` 
drawOn: aCanvas
 aCanvas isShadowDrawing
  ifTrue: [^ aCanvas fillOval: bounds fillStyle: self fillStyle borderWidth: 0 borderColor: nil].
 aCanvas fillOval: bounds fillStyle: self fillStyle borderWidth: borderWidth borderColor: borderColor. `code`
But how to draw a part of a circle or an arc?
It would be nice, if you could give me a code snipplet.

Comment: And cheat you out of all your fun!

Comment: Now that you know where Morphs draw themselves, how do you tweak that method in your submorph to do what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your update, but I'm a SmallTalk beginner and tried to solve it for some hours now, without any proper result. I tried to use CircleMorph and the Arc. Here is what I tried with the circle morph:
    `|circle|
    circle := CircleMorph new.
    circle setProperty: #referencePosition toValue: (circle   position + 20).  
    circle changed.
    circle openInWorld.`
But that wasn't your intent with the clipping rectangle, or?

Comment: Okay, I didn't want to torture you ;-) I just think it's so important (and often missed) for new Smalltalkers to realize that the image is a world of living examples. Given your response, I suggest you start with some free Smalltalk books (http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks.html) to get the basics down. The "... By Example" ones are a good first choice.

Comment: Thank you! :) I've tried and it works fine. Yes, I already started to work through the "Squeak By Example". But there is a strange effect, by dragging this morph a little bit around, it produces some rendering bugs. It shows in the center of the old circle a little rectangle, is it only a bug in my image?

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure as I wrote it on Pharo. I would ask on the Squeak mailing list.